# Execute function for each index in array

Tags: jquery, pdfmake

Im using the pdfmake to create client-side pdf. I have a function that creates the pdf and I have a array with data.

```
function createPDF(data) {
  var docDefinition = { ... };
  pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download(data.customer + '.pdf');
}
```

and then I have this in my ajax request:

```
$.each(data, function( index, value ) {
  createPDF(value);
});
```

If I only have one index with data the pdf is created correct but if i have two "index" with different data, it creates two pdf:s but with the same filename (appends a 1 to filename) and the data on both created pdf's is both from the last index only.

Comment: What's in `value`, and what's in `docDefinition`? It's impossible to answer why you're getting the same name, when you don't post any of the data ?

Comment: That shouldn't be hapening. Nothing in your code as-is would cause a duplicate unless there's duplicates in your data.

Comment: Can you post the data? You could add a console.log(value) right above createPDF(value) to verify what the contents are

Comment: Object
customer
:
"customer1"
Array[6]
period
:
"2016-11"
period_full
:
"November 2016"
total
:
14062.5
vat
:
2812.5
__proto__
:
Object

Object
customer
:
"customer450"
Array[6]
period
:
"2016-11"
period_full
:
"November 2016"
total
:
13256.5
vat
:
3315.3
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: It must be something in the pdfmake lib because if i do: alert(data.customer); it displays the name of the two diff fields and after that it tries to download/save the pdf two times with same name + content